# Сборка html скелета из vue.js data[]

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Начал изучение vue.js, столкнулся с проблемкой:
Настроил прокси, делаю запрос к API одного сайта, ответ(массив с параметрами картинок) записываю в `data`, выглядит все примерно так:

```
items[data[{src="src",title="tit"}{...}{...}],meta[]]
```

Как при помощи какого нить js цикла получить из массива `data` простой html, вида

```
<img src="src"/>
<img src="src"/>
<img src="src"/>
```

Я так понял нужно для начала спарсить эту JSON строку в массив. Но как скормить тому же `JSON.parse` эту vue data?

Answer (score 2):

смог сделать, используя [`v-for`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) и [`v-bind`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#%D0%90%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B):

```
<div v-for="item in items.data">
    <img :src="item.url">
</div>
```